# Which character set is safe for Mysqli->real_escape_string

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding, mysqli

While, I was reading about `mysqli->real_escape_string`, in [PHP.net#mysqli_real_escape_string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php). Few line, I could not understand what they mean, and which character set is safe while using `real_escape_string`

> Caution Security: the default character set
>
> The character set must be set either at the server level, or with the
> API function mysqli_set_charset() for it to affect
> mysqli_real_escape_string(). See the concepts section on character
> sets for more information.

Can someone please explain me, Whether `utf-8` or `default latin` is safe or not :-

Here is their code snippet describing situation here https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

What does this mean ?

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

// Will not affect $mysqli->real_escape_string();
$mysqli->query("SET NAMES utf8");

// Will not affect $mysqli->real_escape_string();
$mysqli->query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");

// But, this will affect $mysqli->real_escape_string();
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8');

?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ANY charset if you are using `mysqli_set_charset()`

Also, `utf-8` and default `latin` are safe even if you aren't.

There are two sides involved in the process. A server and a client. Where client is your PHP script. So, just because escaping being done on the client side (i.e. in PHP), PHP have to know how to escape the data. This is what exactly `mysqli_set_charset()`- it does either let server know the incoming data encoding AND does let `real_escape_string` know what encoding data in.

While `SET NAMES` query does only part of the job, informing server only, leaving `real_escape_string` in the default state. However, either `utf-8` and default `latin` are invulnerable anyway.

Comment: And what if i am not using any `mysqli_set_charset()` function, Am i still safe ?